# wordpress theme What is the purpose

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I am a rails programmer basically who is looking to move towards wordpress for a project which involves conversion of paper based magazine / newspaper to an online version. I have developed rails app with HTML themes before and understand the HTML themes basically are concerned with front end logic. How wordpress themes are in that respect?? They are a bit expensive but do they have any back end functionality as well. I  need some help understanding if i am thinking in the right manner. The theme has homepage which has multiple posts from multiple categories. Will i be able to put post with some categories and they will automatically appear as they shown in the homepage or do i have to manually select which post goes where. Regards

Comment: This is too broad for [so]. in any case you'd be better reading through a Wordpress primer for some of this iformation. You can ask questions on [wordpress.se] but check their help centre before you post there.

Comment: You can start with this template which is basic wordpress theme http://html5blank.com/ then you can work on it with php and html and get your work done.follow this to get more idea about wordpress themes development http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: I understand its a bit broad but i read two wordpress book back to back but couldn't find anything relevent with the themeforest aftermarket themes. I mean i undertand post appear in their chronological order on generic themes but a themeforest themes demo page has lot of post from different categories on different positions. Is it like the theme's backend is also customised to accomodate post for categories and they automatically go onto their relevent positions or placements on the homepage.

Comment: I think you should at least try to make a wordpress website first then post questions when you are having trouble. Because we don't know what kind of positions you would like your categories/posts. Would you like to list each post with it's image and summary? Would you like the links of the categories on the sidebar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each **post** in WP can be tagged and categorized. The posts can then be pulled from the database by various criteria - author, category, tag, date etc.

Read more here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

You could assign various columns on your homepage to display posts from different categories.

There are also different kinds of posts (post formats) such as image, video, quote etc. - which could all be displayed differently, depending on the theme (template).

Posts, post formats, categories, tags - all of these are a part of the standard WordPress install and are independent from the theme. The theme simply takes advantage of these features.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is essentially just like any other CMS. You can make it do pretty much anything you want it to do. If you want all the posts to display on the homepage, you can. If you only want specific posts to display you can do that too with either categories or tags. All you need to know is some PHP and check out the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) for all the functions available.

If you are just wanting to buy a theme then obviously don't get the flexibility unless you hack the theme a bit.